# How to change or disable autochange of wallpaper in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, themes

I have installed couple of Windows 10 themes which has some cool wallpapers. I have noticed that the wallpapers keeps changing automatically in some specific time duration. Is there a way to disable this auto change feature?

**Name of the Theme:** Auckland's One Tree Hill by lan Rushton

Comment: The default is static. You either changed it yourself or the theme you're using has that feature by default.

Comment: Yes, the theme has the feature by default and I would like to change that feature.

Comment: Can you manage it via the normal Windows background settings? If not you need to [edit] and update your question with that information and, of course, with what that theme is.